# Is there anyway to preserve comments for interface in typescript4.0?

Tags: javascript, tsc, typescript4.0

My .ts file like this:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} ITest 
 * @property {string} a
 */
export interface ITest {
  a: string
}

/**
 * @function test
 * @params {string} a
 */
export function test (a: string): void {
  console.log('a', a)
}
```

when i use tsc to compile this file to .js, ***the comment for interface*** will be removed.

Is there anyway to ***preserve this comment in .js***?

The version of tsc is ***4.1.3***

Comment: Because interfaces are removed while transpiling, and jsdoc comments are associated with TS items. Make it a normal (not jsdoc) comment

Comment: @RajKumar I don't think this relates to jsdoc

Comment: @ChayimFriedman thats the problem...in my project, i use jsdoc to mark .ts, then use jsdoc-to-markdown to parse .js and generate README.md by my own style...i can do that through moving the comment below the interface or another file, but the code will be so ugly and unreadable...

Comment: Generate docs from ts, not js